# How to return a string with quotes on output

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code:

```js
function unusedDigits(numbers) {
    let s = numbers.join('');
    let arr = s.split('');
    let ch = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    let arraRes = [];


    for (let i = 0; i < ch.length; i++){
        if (!arr.includes(ch[i])) {
           arraRes += ch[i];
        }
    }

    return String(arraRes); // also tried return arraRes + "";
}

console.log(unusedDigits([12, 34, 56, 78])); //09
console.log(unusedDigits([2015, 8, 26]));  //3479
```

But I can't understand why a number on output. I need on output numbers with quotes - "09" and "3479"

Comment: Did you try `console.log(typeof unusedDigits([12, 34, 56, 78]));`?

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```js
arraRes += ch[i];
```

Converts the array into a string. You should use `push()` to add stuff to an array. This way the array is preserved and you're getting an array of string as return

---

```js
function unusedDigits(numbers) {
    let s = numbers.join('');
    let arr = s.split('');
    let ch = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    let arraRes = [];


    for (let i = 0; i < ch.length; i++){
        if (!arr.includes(ch[i])) {
           arraRes.push(ch[i]);
        }
    }

    return arraRes;
}

console.log(unusedDigits([12, 34, 56, 78])); //09
console.log(unusedDigits([2015, 8, 26]));  //3479
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways:

**Example with string simple concat**

```js
function unusedDigits(numbers) {
    let s = numbers.join('');
    let arr = s.split('');
    let ch = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];    
    let strRes= '';

    for (let i = 0; i < ch.length; i++){
        if (!arr.includes(ch[i])) {           
           strRes += ch[i] + ', ';
        }
    }
        return strRes;    
}

console.log(unusedDigits([12, 34, 56, 78])); //09
console.log(unusedDigits([2015, 8, 26]));  //3479
```

**Example with array**

```js
function unusedDigits(numbers) {
    let s = numbers.join('');
    let arr = s.split('');
    let ch = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    let arraRes = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < ch.length; i++){
        if (!arr.includes(ch[i])) {
           arraRes.push(ch[i]);
        }
    }

    return String(arraRes); // also tried return arraRes + "";
}

console.log(unusedDigits([12, 34, 56, 78])); //09
console.log(unusedDigits([2015, 8, 26]));  //3479
```

Conclusion: I would prefer the first one because you dont need to cast the array back to an string.

Comment: Also, in some resource I got an error TypeError: numbers.join is not a function . Why this error?

Comment: @Ector This error means that you dont pass an array into the function. can you check this, please?!

Comment: I really dont know how to pass an array into the function in this case

Comment: @Ector `const arr = [1,2,3];`  // that is an array. Then you can pass the variable arr to your function. like thta: `unusedDigits(arr)`